# Can Delphi DX Seattle FMX run apps on IOS 8 and IOS 9 in the same .IPA file with 9.1 SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi, firemonkey

Deploying to IOS 9 phones work fine
but we noticed that IOS 8 devices crash on startup, just after the splash screen

We have the following
XCode 7.1
with 9.1 SDK

We tested with a blank app that just had a label on it. No other code

is anyone else having this problem?
this is the crash report

**Reason: Incompatible library version: Project1 requires version 112.0.97 or later, but libobjc.A.dylib provides version 1.0.0**

```
Incident Identifier: 8638EEE7-AF10-4682-AF82-D78A2896ECFE
CrashReporter Key:   ef24ace2d3474ac7014dcd56b44f9e2629ef01fa
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,2
Process:             Project1 [15566]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/06F1CCC5-96A7-422D-8661-C2B9EB9B2DB5/Project1.app/Project1
Identifier:          Project1
Version:             1.0.0.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-11-02 09:40:21.736 +1100
Launch Time:         2015-11-02 09:40:21.667 +1100
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000120089088 Triggered by Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/06F1CCC5-96A7-422D-8661-C2B9EB9B2DB5/Project1.app/Project1
  Reason: Incompatible library version: Project1 requires version 112.0.97 or later, but libobjc.A.dylib provides version 1.0.0
  Dyld Version: 353.12

Binary Images:
0x120088000 - 0x1200affff dyld arm64  <de589e6153453237a6cf724cb236d83c> /usr/lib/dyld
0x183c50000 - 0x183faefff CoreFoundation arm64  <72f7e261b2ec35e39e44417e4d77a241> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x194eec000 - 0x194eedfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <c8f384fcfb6030eab8a9801af2699c9a> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x1951d4000 - 0x1951f6fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <37e33decd1ee3219bc23680232b92729> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1952a8000 - 0x19539bfff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <d3d3af911e6f3360b85b36fe4eb85b9d> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x1959ec000 - 0x195be8fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <7ffbdd0399053da98cabd7c7737a12bf> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use IOS 8.4 SDK it will work on both IOS8 an IOS9.

There is also a [hotfix](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/30398) available that fixes the issue so you can use the IOS9 SDK.

Comment: we reinstalled the hot-fix and it seems to be working